# Can addition and muliplication be simultaneously easy?

Tags: computational-complexity

*I just did a stint at a math festival, and had a quick conversation with a young student about how different notation systems make different operations easy. On the train home, I started wondering the following:*

Is there a finite alphabet $\Sigma$ and a computable function $f: \mathbb{Z}\to \Sigma^*$ such that there are operations $\star_1,\star_2$ on $\Sigma^*$ such that

- both $\star_1$ and $\star_2$ are computable by linear-time-in-length-of-input Turing machines over the alphabet $\Sigma$, and
- for all $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $f(a+b)=f(a)\star_1f(b)$ and $f(a\cdot b)=f(a)\star_2 f(b)$?

Intuitively, this would amount to a (perhaps massively unwieldy) notation system in which both addition and multiplication are computationally easy. Getting one or the other to be easy is, well, easy - standard notation makes addition easy and prime factorization makes multiplication easy - but I don't see how to achieve both at once. On the other hand, I also don't see any concrete obstacles.

Note that I'm not requiring $ran(f)$ to be low-complexity, or restricting the algebraic behavior of $\star_1$ and $\star_2$ off of that set. In particular, $(\Sigma^*;\star_1,\star_2)$ need not even be a ring. I'm happy to assume standard complexity-theoretic conjectures especially for the purposes of getting a negative result (e.g. [that standard integer multiplication is $\Omega(n\log(n))$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Computational_complexity_of_multiplication)).

---

EDIT: the question is trivial as posed; a more interesting question is what happens if we further require $f$ to not blow up too much, but that would be a different question.

Comment: You can pad the numbers to be long enough that even $O(n^2)$ multiplication is linear

Comment: If your numbers are bounded are can use a [residue number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_number_system)

Comment: @CommandMaster Arbitrary integers aren't bounded, so residue systems aren't helpful. I'm not sure what your first comment means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you allow $|f(n)| = \Omega(|n|)$, then you can have $f(n) = 0^{|n|^2} n$ (this is string concatenation). It's easy to see that both multiplication and addition are linear in the size of their input under this $f$. You can even have $f(n) = 0^{|n| \log |n|} n$ if you use an $O(n\log n)$ multiplication algorithm.

If you require $|f(n)| = O(|n|)$, then I'm not sure, but the algorithms I can think about - using either FFT or a residue number system - require some kind of inefficient normalization step, to adjust for the number being bigger (and perform carry in the case of FFT).

Just as a side note, $f$ has to be polynomial in $n$, because you can get $f(n)$ using $O(\log n)$ applications of $\star_1 , \star_2$.

Comment: Ah yes, quite right, I was being foolish.